# What caused Eve to die?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to the Female Krogan?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55413/what-happened-to-the-female-krogan)

When playing curing the genophage, Eve (the Krogan female) had been killed while the cure was being made, but apparently other people had her survive. What caused this change in storyline and does it affect later play?

Answer (score 2):

Eve dies if Mordin did not have access to Maelon's data from the **Mass Effect 2** mission *Old Blood*.

There are two ways that he wouldn't have access: If you completed the mission in ME2, but chose to *destroy the data*, or if you *never completed the mission* in ME2. The latter of these is the default assumption in a New Game without an imported save.

Without Maelon's data, Mordin is unable to effectively counteract the immunodeficiency that is a side effect of the experimental Genophage cure to which Eve was exposed. Since Mordin is unable to treat her, Eve doesn't make it.

The only way to keep Eve alive is to complete *Old Blood* on an imported character, and **save the data**.

Eves survival has two major effects:

1. If Eve dies, there is a -50 modifier on Krogan War Assets. Her survival prevents this.
2. If Eve survives, you are unable to convince Mordin to sabotage the cure -  the only way to do so is to [kill Mordin yourself. You monster.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVuMXjpANmw)

Comment: I did shoot Mordin while playing a renegade shepard, then I felt bad and reloaded, it was one of the few paragon acts I committed on that renegade playthrough since Mordin's one of my favorite characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think its related to a descision of the second game, like says [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56848/will-an-imported-me3-shepard-be-the-same-as-a-new-shepard-story-wise), a default Shepard :

> Shepard did not help Mordin, as such no chance was made to save or
>   destroy the genophage cure data.

I did help Mordin save the genophage cure data. And stopped the mad salarian scientist that did barbaric experiments to cure the genophage.

So in your save, Eve had to suffer longer those barbaric experiments, resulting in her death. That's my guess.

Comment: Right out-of-game explanation in terms of mission completion, wrong in-game explanation in terms of why Eve didn't make it.